# How to delete a specific occurrence with a delete button?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have an iteration in my code which show for each line : ID / Name / Button Delete. You can see the image below. I would like when i click on one of the delete button that the data on the same line be deleted.
I try my best, you can see my code. How i can do it ?
Thank you a lot.

[image]

```
from tkinter import *

import mysql.connector


def main():

    root = Tk()

    conn = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='', host='localhost', 
                                   database='showmanager')
    my_cursor = conn.cursor()

    var_i = 3

    def del_customer():
        my_cursor.execute("DELETE FROM `spectator` "
                          "WHERE `spectator`.`id_customer` = "+user[0]+"")

    my_cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM spectator")
    users = my_cursor.fetchall()

    for user in users:
        label = Label(root, text=user, font=9)
        label.grid(row=int(var_i), column=1)
        Button(root, text="Delete spectator", font=9, height=1, 
               command=del_customer).grid(row=int(var_i), column=4)
        var_i = var_i + 1
    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: pass the user id as argument to the `del_customer` function: `def del_customer(id_):` and in it do `... \`id_customer\` = " + id` and in the loop do `command=lambda id_=user[0]: del_customer(id_)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the customer ID and corresponding widgets (label and button) to `del_customer()` so that you can remove the record in the database based on the customer ID and the corresponding label and button inside the function:

```py
def del_customer(cust_id, widgets):
    my_cursor.execute("DELETE FROM spectator WHERE id_customer = %s", [cust_id])
    conn.commit()  # make the change effective
    # remove the corresponding label and button
    for w in widgets:
        w.destroy()

...

for user in users:
    label = Label(root, text=user)
    label.grid(row=var_i, column=1)
    btn = Button(root, text="Delete spectator")
    btn.grid(row=var_i, column=4)
    var_i += 1
    # pass the customer ID, label and button to del_customer()
    btn['command'] = lambda cust_id=user[0], widgets=(label, btn): del_customer(cust_id, widgets)
```